# JavaScript Does given String exists as variable and function

Tags: javascript

I have a variable with has a member variable which is a function

```
let test = {
 setup: function() { ...}
}
```

From some other source, I get the String "test.setup"

How can i check if

a.) variable test exists

b.) variable test has a child called setup

c.) the child setup is a function ?

d.) call the function

I already tested

```
let variableName = "test.setup";

window[variableName] 
// undefined

{}.toString.call(variableName ) === '[object Function]' 
// VM2052:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

window.hasOwnProperty("test")
// false
```

It would be nice, if you could solve my problem. It would be enough for me to see if there is a such a function and call it if its there. Otherwise Inform the user that there is no such a function.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Needing to dynamically know the names of variables is often an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and has a pretty strong code smell that leads to needing things like `eval()`. If you need to dynamically access something with a string key, that something should be part of a larger data structure, then the problem goes away.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I agree. It's a symptom of a problem.

Comment: @MarkMeyer sometimes as developer you do not have the possibilities to change the bigger data structure and have to work with, what was given to you =(

Comment: `let` and `const` have block scope, but if you declare the variable with `var`, it'll have either global or local function scope (depending if it's declared inside a function or not). So if you declare it with `var` outside any functions, you can use `window["variableNameHere"]` to check if it exists. However, I do agree with the above: you should be defining it as an enclosed object and checking if the "variable name" exists as a key. If you can't access the original variable, at least you can copy it to one you can change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *easiest* and less *secure* way is to use `eval()`. Never use `eval()` with user generated data as it's an attack vector.

```
let test = { setup: function() { return "HelloWorld"; }
let x = eval("typeof test.setup");
console.log(typeof x); // prints function
console.log(x()); // prints "HelloWorld";
```

You will get an error if ".setup" is evaluated on an undefined variable. So you can use `try/catch` to handle this.

```
function exists(value) {
      try {
          return eval(value);
      } catch(e) {
          return undefined;
      }
}

console.log(exists("typeof test.setup")); // prints a type if it exists, or undefined
```